# How to automate testing of multiuser android app?

Tags: android, testing, automated-tests

We have an app, that is synchronizing with remote DB, and all users can modify this db. More over, each user has some data private to it, which is synchronized only between this users devices and not with other devices.

### So, what are the best practices for automation testing of such app?

---

How can I see it:

We need at least 2 devices, to make changes on first devices and finding this changes become visible on second devices. At least, this the most high level tests that i do by hands. There are also two different cases, when those 2 "devices" belongs to one user (I use users Google account to differentiate between users) and to different users...

### How this multiuser environment can be automated for tests?

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to probably do something less than ideal to test this, either create a special test build that allows you to override the account you are in (letting you jump between two) or build a way to have different databases for different tests that are in the state you need for any given user (e.g. by having a different endpoint for your application to hit for each test).

Without seeing your code these are the most general ideas, it might be a way pops up if i knew more but sadly I do not have access to that information.